# offline install for py2neo in ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, neo4j, py2neo

I downloaded the .zip from the py2neo github and placed in the site-packages folder and ran

```
pip install py2neo
```

Everything looks like it's in the right place (I compared to windows setup and they both contain the same files in the same places) but when I run a .py I get:

```
ImportError: No module named batch *
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your paths aren't setup correctly. To install, I would recommend simply running the `pip install py2neo` line without first downloading the zip and allowing `pip` to pull py2neo from PyPI. Alternatively, if you are trying to avoid using a network connection from your server, run `python setup.py install` from within a copy of the GitHub repository.

**Note**: You will want to checkout the latest release branch from the GitHub repository before installing. At the time of writing, this is named `release/1.6.4`.

Comment: I pulled the py2neo-master and not the release.